# Factors calculation in RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa, factoring

You are given $d\bmod(p-1)$ , $d\bmod(q-1)$ , $\operatorname{invert}(p,q)$ and $p\bmod2^{200}$, the public exponent is $e=65537$.

$\operatorname{invert}(p,q)$ is the answer of $ p*x \equiv 1 (mod\quad q)$

$d$ is the private exponent, the modulus is unknown.

Is there some way to calculate $p$, $q$?

Comment: The added information tells that $\operatorname{invert}(p,q)$ designates $p^{-1}\bmod q$. That's _not_ $q_\text{inv}=q^{-1}\bmod p$ usually part of an RSA private key.

Comment: @fgrieu: actually, it is usually a part of the RSA private key (swap which prime is called $p$ and which is called $q$)

Comment: @Manc  You may want to consider voting up the answer that you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are given $d \bmod(p−1)$.., the public exponent is $e=65537$.  Is there some way to calculate $p$?

Well, we know that $d_p = d \bmod p-1$ and $e$ are related by $d_p \cdot e = 1 + kp$, for some integer $k$, and that $k < 65537$

So, do a partial factorization of $d_p \cdot e - 1$ into $a \cdot b$, where $a$ consists of factors below 65537 and $b$ has no such factors (which is quite easy).  We know that $p = (a/c) b$, where $c$ is a factor of $a$; $a$ is relatively small, and so there are only a few such factors to consider.  And because we know

> $p \bmod 2^{200}$

It's easy to distinguish which one it is.

And, for the other half of the question:

> Is there some what to calculate $q$

We can use the same trick, except using the known $p^{-1} \bmod q$ value as the distinguisher...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!❤